# How can i get all the metrics where two label have same values using promql?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am new to promql. So not sure if promql supports my requirement or not.

```
max_over_time(cbnode_systemstats_cpu_utilization_rate{instance="a",node="a"}[6h])
```

This above query gives me result  of max cpu utilization in past 6 hr for instance a single instnace a.

However I want a query which fetches all metrics for all the instances where instance and node has same value. Something similar to below:

```
max_over_time(cbnode_systemstats_cpu_utilization_rate{instance = node}[6h])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy elegant way to do that.

But you can utilize `label_replace`, logic of label matching for binary operations and a pinch of ingenuity.

```
label_replace(cbnode_systemstats_cpu_utilization_rate{}, "pseudoid", "$1", "instance", "(.*)")
 == label_replace(cbnode_systemstats_cpu_utilization_rate{}, "pseudoid", "$1", "node", "(.*)")
```

Here we add to LHS metric new label called `pseudoid` with value of `instance`, and same for RHS, but with value of `node`.

Result will be returned only if all labels are the same, and in turn it will mean that `instance == pseudoid == node`.

Demo of similar query can be seen [here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=go_build_info%7B%7D&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=label_replace(go_build_info%7B%7D%2C%20%22id%22%2C%20%22%241%22%2C%20%22path%22%2C%20%22(.*)%22)%20%3D%3D%20label_replace(go_build_info%7B%7D%2C%20%22id%22%2C%20%22%241%22%2C%20%22version%22%2C%20%22(.*)%22)&g1.tab=1&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h).

Notice that since it is not the instant vector selector, you'll need to use subquery syntax to pass it into `max_over_time`.

You resulting query should look like this:

```
max_over_time(
 (
   label_replace(cbnode_systemstats_cpu_utilization_rate{}, "pseudoid", "$1", "instance", "(.*)")
     == label_replace(cbnode_systemstats_cpu_utilization_rate{}, "pseudoid", "$1", "node", "(.*)")
 )[6h:]
)
```